# DatastoreException: A non-transactional commit may not contain multiple mutations affecting the same entity

Tags: java, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a Apache BEAM pipeline processing streaming data, from google pubsub topic and written into google Datastore. There has been errors surfacing the past few days with the following error message, and choking up the pipeline, causing us to lose data.

```java
com.google.datastore.v1.client.DatastoreException: A non-transactional commit may not contain multiple mutations affecting the same entity., code=INVALID_ARGUMENT
at com.google.datastore.v1.client.RemoteRpc.makeException(RemoteRpc.java:126)
at com.google.datastore.v1.client.RemoteRpc.makeException(RemoteRpc.java:169)
at com.google.datastore.v1.client.RemoteRpc.call(RemoteRpc.java:89)
at com.google.datastore.v1.client.Datastore.commit(Datastore.java:84)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.datastore.DatastoreV1$DatastoreWriterFn.flushBatch(DatastoreV1.java:1326)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.datastore.DatastoreV1$DatastoreWriterFn.finishBundle(DatastoreV1.java:1291)
```

The pipeline is in streaming mode and not batching or windowing the data in any way. So I'm not sure how its possible that the pipeline can be writing duplicate records at the same time. Would like to check:

1. Any way to incorporate duplicate checks before writing to Datastore in a streaming context?
2. How can I attach logs to the exceptions so that I can which sources are producing the errant data and troubleshoot from there?

The BEAM pipeline code is as below:

```java
public class JobPipeline {
    private final Pipeline pipeline;
    private final JobOptions options;

    JobPipeline(JobOptions options) {
        this.options = options;
        this.pipeline = Pipeline.create(options);
    }

    void run() throws IOException {

        PTransform<PBegin, PCollection<String>> input = getInput([pubsub topic]);

        PCollection<KV<String, EnrichedData>> enrichedData = new EnrichmentPipeline(options, input).apply(pipeline);

        pipeline.run();
    }
}

public class EnrichmentPipeline {

    private final JobOptions options;
    private final PTransform<PBegin, PCollection<String>> input;

    public EnrichmentPipeline(JobOptions options,
                          PTransform<PBegin, PCollection<String>> input) {
        this.options = options;
        this.input = input;
    }

    public PCollection<KV<String, EnrichedData>> apply(final Pipeline pipeline) throws IOException {

        PCollection<KV<String, EnrichedData>> enrichedData = pipeline.apply("Reading Data", input)
                                                                 .apply("Transforming Json to Data", ParDo.of(new JsonToData()))
                                                                 .apply("Enrichment", ParDo.of(new EnrichmentFn(options.getProjectId(), options.getReferenceKind())));

        writeIntoDataStore(options.getProjectId(), enrichedData, new EnrichedDataToEntityFn(options.getDataKind()));

        return enrichedData;
    }
}
```

Comment: Looking at the error message, it looks like you've issued a non-transactional commit which is trying to mutate at least more than one entity. Try to change the commit to [Transactional](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/data/rpc/google.datastore.v1#google.datastore.v1.CommitRequest) to avoid this.

Comment: @Mangu I'm not familiar with how apache beam processes elements in a streaming context, but the way I understand your suggestion, seems like DatastoreIO is processing the elements at least in chunks and not individual elements? If that's the case, won't all the elements writing to datastore in the same chunk all get rejected?

Comment: The pipeline code you have their does not include any calls to Datastore or any use of Beam's `DatastoreIO`. Can you provide the code for how you are writing to Datastore?